# I'm having problems using jquery-masonry in a drop down menu

Tags: jquery-masonry

I'd like to use jquery masonry within a drop down menu, to organize the dynamic menu item blocks (images and text) in a complex drop down menu.

I'm having a couple of issues.

First of all, if I start with display:none then masonry doesn't do any position calculations. Since I'm using masonry with a drop down menu, I can't open the page with the drop down visible.

Secondly, the menu container has to be position:absolute so that the drop down opens Over the continuing page and doesn't push down the text below the menu. Masonry pushes the rest of the page down.

Thirdly, with IE 8 and 9 (didn't try 7 yet), when the I hide and show the dropdown, the blocks of items start off unorganized and then instantly switch to the organized masonry layout. It's the flash on every hide and show that I don't understand and can't get rid of.

Has anyone successfully used jquery masonry within a dropdown menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the first issue, just use `visibility:hidden` and in hover event `visibility: visible` instead of `display:none` & `display:block`.